# Display thumbnails for certain category posts

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails, customization

I have wondered about the web and came across this beautiful piece of code:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()){ 

the_post_thumbnail();  

}else{ 

  echo '<img src="' .  get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_post_thumb.jpg" />';

}
```

What it does, is adds a default thumbnail to every single post. That's good for a portfolio blog, but what if I have loads of categories, e.g. one category is tutorials and another is music - I must have different default thumbnails for those categories.

Can anybody please explain to me how I can customize this code to show different *default* thumbnails for different categories?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below shows the "post-thumbnail" aka the featured image if the post has one, if not depending on the category, the default thumbnail is shown (with the comments, the code should be self-explanatory):

```
<?php

// If the post has a featured image defined use it
if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();

// Default image for Technology category
} elseif ( is_category( 'technology' ) ) {
    echo '<img src="' .  get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_technology_post_thumb.jpg" />';

// Default image for Gadgets category
} elseif ( is_category( 'gadgets' ) ) {
    echo '<img src="' .  get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_gadgets_post_thumb.jpg" />';

// Default image for all others
} else {
    echo '<img src="' .  get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/default_post_thumb.jpg" />';
}

?>
```

**Suggested Reading:** [WordPress Codex — Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: Do I put this in functions.php?

Comment: @Nick Then mark it as the answer :)

Comment: No, it doesn't go into the theme's functions.php. You need to add it in your template files (index.php, archive.php, search.php, content.php, or single.php, etc.) depending on where you want the thumbnail to be shown.

Comment: ok. I'll try that. By the way, does it matter where I put above code in page.php/index.php?

Comment: Yes. In general, code in index.php shows on homepage, archive.php on archive pages (category & tag archives), search.php on search results pages, single.php in posts, and so on. So yes, where you add the code matters.

Comment: @Nick You can read more about [Template Hierarchy on WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and the [Template files list here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List).